# How to print sklearn confusion_matrix output from within a function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, output, confusion-matrix

`confusion_matrix` works properly from the command line on my notebook, but I can't seem to make it print its output when written inside a function. It is applied to the same arrays in both cases.

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you share the code that you tried

Comment: @Jeril I know I should have - but didn't because it's longish and complicated-ish so I thought it would only make the question heavier. At the same time I thought this is probably a generic question where I'm missing something obvious. And indeed I did, as shown by the answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a function as the last command in a notebook cell, the output will be printed automatically, however this is not the case when it is wrapped in a function. In this case you would have to call the print() function somewhere within the function.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

a = np.array([1,0,1,1,0,1])
b = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,0])

def show_confusion(a, b):
    print(confusion_matrix(a, b))

show_confusion(a, b)
```

Comment: [Oh, previous comment disappeared,] thank you for your quick and instructive answer! I can't believe I didn't think of it btw.